# Query missing months in which we haven't sold anything?

Tags: php, mysql

My query is:

```
$sql="SELECT  COUNT(`Variant`) AS tsold, MONTHNAME(`sold_date`) AS mname FROM `vehicle_sold` GROUP BY MONTH(`sold_date`) ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {  


    echo $row["mname"],"---", $row["tsold"],"<br />";
```

}

which gives me the below result:

```
January---1
February---2
March---7
April---11
May---6
July---1
```

There are no sales in June so what I want is  the query to return "June---0" for example. If it also shows the next months up to December it's ok. I'd like the following output:

```
January---1
February---2
March---7
April---11
May---6
June---0
July---1
Aug---0
Sept---0
Oct---0
Nov---0
Dec---0
```

Comment: Add your query first.

Comment: You query might have the condition: if no sell, don't fetch the row.

Comment: You can do it in the query or you can take the array which contains all months. If value of mname is found in array then remove that(month) from array. Assign '0' to all remaining values(months) in the array.

Comment: You can use date() function in place of $row["mname"] and every time increase it

Comment: I forget to put the query, Please check now and help me with query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have actually no data in the database if you did not sell anything. Hence its a bit hard to generate a month without info.

You want an array with all the months, corresponding with the amount of sales. 
I would suggest you make something like this:

Prepare an array with the months with all the values on 0 as default (you can make this array list 'nicer', but just now as example).

```
$data['March'] = 0;
$data['April'] = 0;
```

Now you can iterate like you did

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$data[$row["mname"]] = $row["tsold"];
}
```

If it does not get filled by the database, the value would still be 0. Otherwise it gets overwritten by the database value.

Answer (score 3):

Use an array of month names -

```
$months = array('January', 'February', ..., 'December');
```

Generate and array with the data returned from database -

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[$row["mname"]] = $row["tsold"];
}
```

And print them accordingly -

```
foreach($months as $value) {
    echo $value.' - '. (array_key_exists($value, $data) ? $data[$value] : 0) . '<br/>';
}
```